# A little exercise about normal subgroups

Tags: matrices, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Good morning, I am having some problems with this exercise.

I have to show that $N:=\left \{ M=\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
1 &b \\ 
 0&1 
\end{smallmatrix}\bigr), b \in \mathbb{Z} \right \}\subseteq G$ is a normal subgroup of the group $G:=\left \{ M=\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
a &b \\ 
 0&d 
\end{smallmatrix}\bigr),\  a,b,d \in \mathbb{Z}, det(M)=\pm1\right \}$ with matrix multiplication.

I decided to prove the following: $Ng=gN$

$\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
1 &b \\ 
 0&1 
\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)*\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
a &b \\ 
 0&d 
\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)=\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
a &c+bd \\ 
 0&d 
\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)\neq \bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
a &b \\ 
 0&d 
\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)*\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
1 &b \\ 
 0&1 
\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)=\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
a &ab+c \\ 
 0&d 
\end{smallmatrix}\bigr) $
So this proves that $N$ is not a normal subgroup of $G$.

What I am doing wrong?

EDIT:
So I have done the following:
$gNg^{-1} \in N$
so

$\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
a &c \\ 
 0&d 
\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)*\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
1 &b \\ 
 0&1 
\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)*\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
a &c \\ 
 0&d 
\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)^{-1}=\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
ad &a^2b \\ 
 0&ad 
\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)*\frac{1}{ad}=\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
1 &\frac{ab}{d} \\ 
 0&1
\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)=\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
1 &b_{1} \\ 
 0&1
\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)\in N$ since $d$ and $a$ are $-1$ or $1$

From this follows that N is a normal subgroup

Comment: $Ng=gN$ doesn't mean $ng=gn$ for every $n$ in $N$ and every $g$ in $G$. It means $ng=gn'$ for some $n'$ in $N$, not necessarily $n'=n$.

Comment: Notice that $Ng = gN$ is a set equality. It doesn’t guarantee that $ng = gn$, but rather that for all $n\in N$ there is an $n’\in G$ such that $ng =gn’$ (and vice versa)

Comment: $Ng=gN$ does not mean $\forall n \in N, ng=gn$  but $\forall n \in N, ng\in gN$ and $ \forall n \in N, gn\in Ng$.

Comment: In addition to what everyone else have (correctly) said: note you also have confusion with two $b$'s: in $\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\0&d\end{pmatrix}$ and in $\begin{pmatrix}1&b\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$. There is no reason why those two $b$'s need to be the same, so please use a different symbol (say, $b'$) for one of them!

Comment: Just so you know: We are not all in the same time zone.

Comment: Note that you also need to show that it's a subgroup!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have done the "normal" part in your edit. Well done!

However, you need to show that $N$ is a subgroup of $G$.

To this end, use the one-step subgroup test.

Since $I=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}\in N$, we have $N\neq\varnothing$.

By definition, $N\subseteq G$.

Let $X=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & x\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}, Y=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & y\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ be in $N$. Then $x,y\in \Bbb Z$ and

$$\begin{align}
XY^{-1}&=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & x\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & y\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}^{-1}\\
&=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & x\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}\ast\frac{1}{1-0}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -y\\ -0 & 1\end{pmatrix}\\
&=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & x-y\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix},
\end{align}$$

which is in $N$ as $x-y\in\Bbb Z$.

Hence $N\le G$.

Hence $N\unlhd G$.

Comment: Thank you a lot :)

Comment: You're welcome, @MarcoDJ01. Please don't forget to upvote and accept this answer if you see fit to :)